# TAPEX (large-sized model) cannot find average/difference

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence

I am using [TAPEX](https://huggingface.co/microsoft/tapex-large-finetuned-wtq) for table question answering.

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqL
import pandas as pd

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("microsoft/tapex-base-finetuned-wtq")
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("microsoft/tapex-base-finetuned-wtq")
```

**here is a table**

```
data = {"Actors": ["Brad Pitt", "Leonardo Di Caprio", "George Clooney"], "Number of movies": ["87", "53", "69"]}
```

I am trying to answer the following Questions:
`questions = ["how many movies does Leonardo Di Caprio have?","how many more movies does Leonardo Di Caprio have than George Clooney?","what's the first name of the actor who has 87 movies?"]`

First and last are ok, but 2nd is incorrect. I have tried different question formats (1-4), even similar to the ones given on the website ([Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0OCF.png)).
[Test01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvdVL.png), [Test02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mllv1.png), [Test03](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwMEY.jpg), [Test04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHrIj.jpg)

I have also tried

`data['Number of movies'] = pd.to_numeric(data['Number of movies'])`

because numbers were string. Still get 36.

The same problem with average, cannot find the mean/ave of number of movies.
[Test05](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFkjr.png)
[Test06](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1loD0.png)

According to later exploration, TAPEX can use AVE operator, so what's the problem?

Is it because it is a "Language " AI & cannot do maths?

Answer (score 0):

It's worth explaining something about complex language models like this: these models are very impressive in their ability to (apparently) "understand" a query and act appropriately most of the time. To a human, this can give the impression that they do understand and therefore can reliably perform certain tasks.

But what these models do is not *understanding* in any way, because [Natural Language Understanding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural-language_understanding) is not solved and may never be solved. These models are extremely advanced at *reproducing* the patterns that they extract from their training data, what they are good at is *mimicking*. Thus one can always unavoidably find a case where they fail, as long as the domain is infinite.

Of course, complex queries are more likely to derail the model: probably this model was trained only with simple queries about accessing a value, so it's simply not trained to calculate anything. An interesting question is why 36? My guess would be that it's just a value which appeared more often during training, so the model defaults to answering it when it has no clue what to do. It's worth noting that a better design would have been to train the model to recognize when it can't answer, and say "Sorry I don't know".